# How to determine if whole-device encryption enabled?

Tags: settings

If someone hands me a Windows Phone 8.1 device, how can I determine if the phone has whole-device encryption enabled? Is there somewhere in the settings that indicates this?

Comment: Why might you care? I.e. what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Whole device encryption is only enabled when the device is linked to a company's domain/network.

Answer (score 1):

The device is only encrypted when it is connected to an exchange or a company account that requires the phone to do so.

> - Device encryption is not enabled by default. Device encryption is automatically enabled in the following scenarios:
>
>   - The user adds an Outlook account to the phone, and the Microsoft Exchange server that it connects to is configured to require device encryption.
>   - The user connects the phone to a company apps account, and the enterprise device management server for the account pushes down a policy to the phone that requires device encryption.

[Secure boot and device encryption overview](https://dev.windowsphone.com/de-de/OEM/docs/Phone_Bring-Up/Secure_boot_and_device_encryption_overview)

Answer (score 0):

On WP 8.1 phones one can check this via the Storage Sense app. If it shows storage encrypted there, the internal phone storage has been secured.